# Highlight the search text - angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript

A messenger displays the search results based on the input given by the user. Need to highlight the word that is been searched, while displaying the result. 
These are the html and component that is been used.

**Component.html**

```
 <div *ngFor = "let result of resultArray">
<div>Id : result.id </div>
<div>Summary : result.summary </div>
<div> Link : result.link </div>
</div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
resultArray : any = [{"id":"1","summary":"These are the results for the searched text","link":"http://www.example.com"}]
```

This resultArray is fetched from hitting the backend service by sending the search text as input. Based on the search text, the result is fetched. Need to highlight the searched text, similar to google search. Please find the screenshot,

[image]

If I search for the word "member", the occurence of the word "member" gets highlighted. How to achieve the same using angular 2. Please suggest an idea on this.

Comment: I found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/adamrecsko/0f28f474eca63e0279455476cc11eca7#gistcomment-2103489) working perfectly

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can do that by creating a pipe and applying that pipe to the **summary** part of array inside `ngfor`. Here is the code for `Pipe`:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'highlight'
})

export class HighlightSearch implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any, args: any): any {
        if (!args) {return value;}
        var re = new RegExp(args, 'gi'); //'gi' for case insensitive and can use 'g' if you want the search to be case sensitive.
        return value.replace(re, "<mark>$&</mark>");
    }
}
```

and then in markup apply it on a string like this:

```
<div innerHTML="{{ str | highlight : 'search'}}"></div>
```

Replace 'search' with the word you want to highlight.

Hope this will help.

Comment: This also replaces the found substring with the searched one, applying the wrong case.

Comment: Clear and simple answer!

Comment: @afe
return value.replace(new RegExp(args, 'gi'), "<mark>$&</mark>");
Will replace with the same case

Comment: Searching for . will select everything, and searching for nothing will create mark for every character (for this is easy, a simple if (!args) {return value;} at the beginning of the function)

Comment: @Jeremy Added that. Thanks for the input.

Comment: HI Thank you for the Answer. But While returning in my HTML i am etting '<mark>3</mark>'

Comment: this should be a pure pipe, its much better for performance

Comment: this doesn't highlight $ (dolor signs in the results)

Comment: This has a security issue. If you pass a string that contain html with script it can xss your app.

Answer (score 13):

The selected answer has the following issues:

1. It will return undefined if there is nothing provided in the search string
2. The search should be case insensitive but that should not replace the original string case.

i would suggest the following code instead

```
transform(value: string, args: string): any {
    if (args && value) {
        let startIndex = value.toLowerCase().indexOf(args.toLowerCase());
        if (startIndex != -1) {
            let endLength = args.length;
            let matchingString = value.substr(startIndex, endLength);
            return value.replace(matchingString, "<mark>" + matchingString + "</mark>");
        }

    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: This did not match multiple occurrences of the word but it did provide a good point about trying to keep the search from obliterating the by overriding the casing.

I submitted an answer that used case sensitive regex to attempt to address the problem. And falls back to case-insensitive when the search is funky.

Answer (score 7):

If you have multiple words in your string than use pipe which accepts array and highlight each word in result.

You can use following pipe for multiple search words:-

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'highlight'
})

export class HighlightText implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any, args: any): any {
        if (!args) {return value;}
        for(const text of args) {
            var reText = new RegExp(text, 'gi');
            value = value.replace(reText, "<mark>" + text + "</mark>");
            //for your custom css
            // value = value.replace(reText, "<span class='highlight-search-text'>" + text + "</span>"); 


        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Split you string to generate array of strings.

```
var searchTerms = searchKey.split(' ');
```

usage:

```
<div [innerHTML]="result | highlight:searchTerms"></div>
```

If you wanted to use custom class :

```
.highlight-search-text {
  color: black;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

All the best!

Comment: It should be `[innerHTML]` not `[innetHTML]`

Comment: Tip: If you change `"<mark>" + text + "</mark>"` to `"<mark>$&</mark>"` it will preserve casing of the highlighted section.

Answer (score 7):

Building on a previous answer (HighlightedText-Component) I ended up with this:

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'highlighted-text',
    template: `
        <ng-container *ngFor="let match of result">
            <mark *ngIf="(match === needle); else nomatch">{{match}}</mark>
            <ng-template #nomatch>{{match}}</ng-template>
        </ng-container>
    `,
})
export class HighlightedTextComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() needle: string;
    @Input() haystack: string;
    public result: string[];

    ngOnChanges() {
        const regEx = new RegExp('(' + this.needle + ')', 'i');
        this.result = this.haystack.split(regEx);
    }
}
```

This way also multiple matches of the needle are highlighted. The usage of this component is similar to the one in the previous answer:

```
<highlighted-text [needle]="searchInput" [haystack]="value"></highlighted-text>
```

For me this approach using a component feels more secure, since I do not have to use "innerHtml".

Comment: This show only the highlighted term. How i can render all the text where it's the highlighted term?

Answer (score 6):

One difficulty the innerHTML method has is in styling the `<mark>` tag. Another method is to place this in a component, allowing for much more options in styling.

**highlighted-text.component.html**

```
<mark *ngIf="matched">{{matched}}</mark>{{unmatched}}
```

**highlighted-text.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "highlighted-text",
    templateUrl: "./highlighted-text.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./highlighted-text.component.css"]
})
export class HighlightedTextComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() needle: String;
    @Input() haystack: String;
    public matched;
    public unmatched;

    ngOnChanges(changes) {
        this.match();
    }

    match() {
        this.matched = undefined;
        this.unmatched = this.haystack;
        if (this.needle && this.haystack) {
            const needle = String(this.needle);
            const haystack = String(this.haystack);
            const startIndex = haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase());
            if (startIndex !== -1) {
                const endLength = needle.length;
                this.matched = haystack.substr(startIndex, endLength);
                this.unmatched = haystack.substr(needle.length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**highlighted-text.component.css**

```
mark {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;       
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

**Usage**

```
<highlighted-text [needle]=searchInput [haystack]=value></highlighted-text>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to escape the search String like this

```
 RegExp.escape = function(string) {
  if(string !== null){ return string.toString().replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&')
  } else return null
};

@Pipe({
    name: 'highlight'
})
export class HighlightPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){ }

  transform(value: any, args: any): any {
    if (!args || value == null) {
      return value;
    }
    // Match in a case insensitive maneer
    const re = new RegExp(RegExp.escape(args), 'gi');

      const  match = value.match(re);



    // If there's no match, just return the original value.
    if (!match) {
      return value;
    }

    const replacedValue = value.replace(re, "<mark>" + match[0] + "</mark>")
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(replacedValue)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Kamal's answer,

The value coming into the transform method, could be a number, perhaps a cast to string `String(value)` would be safe thing to do.

```
transform(value: string, args: string): any {
    if (args && value) {
        value = String(value); // make sure its a string
        let startIndex = value.toLowerCase().indexOf(args.toLowerCase());
        if (startIndex != -1) {
            let endLength = args.length;
            let matchingString = value.substr(startIndex, endLength);
            return value.replace(matchingString, "<mark>" + matchingString + "</mark>");
        }

    }
    return value;
}
```