# Angular 2 search and highlight text

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

I am currently working on an `angular 2` web app which requires users to enter text using an input bar and the input bar text to search for that text inside a div and highlight it, it also wants the whole page to highlight the occurrence of that text using the highlighted scroll bar like you see in the image.

[image]

Comment: Please add some code, what have you tried right now?

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44961759/highlight-the-search-text-angular-2

Comment: I have tried using https://markjs.io/configurator.html however couldn't find anything that would have this highlighting on the scroll bar.