# How to develop search suggestion text box using angular 2/4

Tags: asp.net, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I'am new in Angular. How can i develop a drop down suggestion search box in angular 2/4. when clicking on search button the details are shown using below codes.But am trying while typing on text box the suggestion details need to show. same like Auto complete (During searching, ‘as-you-type’ suggestion to be displayed.)

**component.HTML**

```
        <form role="form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input name="search" 
                            class="form-control" 
                            type="text" 
                            placeholder="Search" 
                            required="" [(ngModel)]='searchcontent'>
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button 
                                class="btn btn-success ProductSearchBtn" 
                                    type="button" 
                                (click)='FetchItemDetailsSearch(searchcontent)'>
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" 
                                        aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <span style="margin-left:10px;">Search</span>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="CommonsubWhiteBg" 
    style='height:850px;overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden' 
    (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of itemdetails;">
            <article class="row" style="margin:0px;">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 EnquiryMore">
                    <a [routerLink]="['/productdetails',item.ItemID]">
                        <h5>{{item.ItemCode + ' - ' + item.ItemDescription}}</h5>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </article>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="!itemdetails" style="margin:0px;">
            <article class="col-md-12">
                <h3>Loading data...</h3>
            </article>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="itemdetails&&itemdetails.length==0" 
            class="ItemNotfoundArea row" style="margin:0px;">
            <article class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Sorry</h1>
                <p>Item Not Found</p>
            </article>
        </ng-container>
    </section>
```

**component.ts file**

```
FetchItemDetailsSearch(itemcodeordesc: string): void {
    this.pageIndex = 1;
    this.searchflag = 1;
    if (itemcodeordesc.length > 0)
        this.searchcontent = itemcodeordesc;
    else {
        itemcodeordesc = undefined
        this.searchcontent = itemcodeordesc;
    }
    this.prevScrollPosition = 0;        
    this._enqService
        .FetchItemDetailsSearch(this.searchcontent, this.pageIndex)
            .subscribe(itemsData => this.itemdetails = itemsData,
                error => {
                    console.error(error);
                    this.statusMessage = 
                        "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
                }
            );
        }
```

**Service.ts **

```
FetchItemDetailsSearch(itemcodeordesc: string, pageIndex: number): 
  Observable<IEnquiryDetails[]> {
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:1234/api/enquirydetails/', 
        { params: 
            { itemcodeordesc: itemcodeordesc, 
              pageIndex: pageIndex } 
        })
    .map((response: Response) => <IEnquiryDetails[]>response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

[image]

**condition**: trying only with Angular 4/2 not jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at angular material auto complete component.

https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples.

You can also have your own custom filter function. Below sample code would give you a way out to achieve the same.
https://stackblitz.com/angular/krlrmgepmrv?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts

or 
Try this

http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/03/simple-search-using-pipe-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 1):

**Please check this answer**

```
   <form role="form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input name="search" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" (keyup)="FetchItemDetailsSearch(searchcontent)" [(ngModel)]="searchcontent">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-success ProductSearchBtn" type="button" (click)='FetchItemDetailsSearch(searchcontent)'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></i><span style="margin-left:10px;">Search</span></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use auto complete plugin like [this](http://oferh.github.io/ng2-completer/#/native) .

Answer (score 0):

Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).