# Angular 2 Highlight Multiple Values Using Pipe

Tags: angular, angular-template, angular-pipe

I currently have a simple search function implemented [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-course-filter-pipe-gm2vhu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhighlight-filter.pipe.ts) that allows a user to search for courses.   The user can input queries multiple queries separated by commas, and I am filtering the results if there exists a match to each tokenized query (done iteratively):

```
search($event) {
      var re = /\s*,\s*/;
      let splitQuery = this.searchText.split(re);
      let numQueries = splitQuery.length;
      let tempCourses = this.courses;
      for (var i = 0;i < numQueries; i ++){
        tempCourses = this.rankAndFilter(tempCourses, splitQuery[i].toUpperCase())
      }
      this.courseResults = this.sortByRank(tempCourses);
```

I would also like for all the queries to be highlighted in the search results as well, to be viewable to the user.  This is the [original highlight pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45363164/6521206) and I have tried to modify it, but it doesn't return each individual word highlighted.

```
transform(value: string, args: string): any {

var re = /\s*,\s*/;

    if (args && value){
        let splitQuery = args.split(re);
        let numQueries = splitQuery.length;
        let returnedHighlighted: String = value; 
        console.log(`number of queries: ${numQueries}`)
        for (var i = 0; i < numQueries; i++){

          console.log(`${i}: ${splitQuery[i]}`)
          let startIndex = value.toUpperCase().indexOf(splitQuery[i].toUpperCase());
          if (startIndex != -1) {
                let endLength = args.length;
                let matchingString = value.substr(startIndex, endLength);
                returnedHighlighted = returnedHighlighted.replace(matchingString, "<mark>" + matchingString + "</mark>");
           }  
        }
        return returnedHighlighted
    }
    return value; }
```

A test case would be the query `linear algebra` returns `89A Statistics` and `54 Mathematics`, a query `linear algebra, probability` returns both courses but with the individual words highlighted, and the query `linear algebra, probability, data science` would only return `89A Statistics` with each individual query highlighted.

In reality this will be applied to over tens of thousands of courses, so any pointers / implementations for time efficiency for either the highlighting or filtering would also be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in one step. Create a regExpresion that search the different values an replace by the < mark>value< /mark>

```
@Pipe({ name: 'highlight' })
export class HighlightPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: string, args: string): any {

    if (args && value){
       var re = new RegExp(args.split(',').join('|'),"gi");
        //e.g. if args was linear,equa, the regExpr will become  /linear|equa/gi
        return value.replace(re,(x)=>"<mark>"+x+"</mark>");
    }
    return value; 
  }
}
```

NOTE: You must check if use an especial characters $, ...

Answer (score 0):

Building off @Eliseo's answer to handle edge cases such as "query," and "query, ":

```
 transform(value: string, args: string): any {

     if (args && value){
           let re_noSpace = /\s*,\s*/;
           let queryList = args.split(re_noSpace).filter(String);
           let re_matchQueries = new RegExp(queryList.join('|'),"gi");
           return value.replace(re_matchQueries,(x)=>"<mark>"+x+"</mark>");
      }
      return value; 
 }
```