# how to bold search pattern in search results in angular 2 material table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2

I searched for "ium". 3 rows matched and showed in search results. How do I now bold just the "ium" in the search results like the iphone phone directory search. Running demo and code is [here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#filtering)

Comment: Click on Filtering on the right hand side Table of contents on the demo page

Comment: Using regexp and plopping in spans on the fly. More effort than a Q&A warrants, start with google like "highlight angular filter results regexp" and come back with a minimal example :)

Comment: Thanks for regex tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to [create a custom pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44962110/9077877) and apply it to the  content within each template expression.

You can, of course, make your `bold.pipe.ts` wrap its passed in value with `<strong></strong>` instead of `<mark></mark>`, so that your filtered results are made bold and not highlighted.

You would have to bind the value of the filtered input to the pipe's arguments, so it would look something like this:

`<td>{{ element.name | bold: filter }}</td>`,
where `filter` is the searched value.

Do note that the linked answer will return undefined on an empty filter value.

*Stack Overflow answer credited to [Fahad Nisar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6261178/fahad-nisar)*

Answer (score 0):

maybe this `bold.pipe.ts`

```
transform(value: any, search: any): any {
 if (!search) { return value; }
 let searchLength = search.length;
 let holder = value.split('');
 let indexAdder = 0;
 let indexs = this.locations(search.toLowerCase(), value.toLowerCase() )
 indexs = indexs.map( (x) => {
  let solution =  x + indexAdder;
  indexAdder += 2;
  return solution;
 })
 indexs.forEach( (i) => {
  holder.splice(i, 0 , "<span class='bold'>")
  holder.splice(i + searchLength +1, 0,  "</span>")
 })
 return holder.join('');
}

locations(substring, searchValue) {
 let indexs = [], i = -1;
 while((i = searchValue.indexOf(substring, i + 1 )) >= 0) {
  indexs.push(i);
 }
 return indexs;
}
```

then in your `component.html`

```
<td [innerHTML]="a.value | bold: getSearchInputValue()">{{a.value}}</td>
```