# Angular 11.0.4 Can't find pipe

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use a pipe to highlight certain text based on a dropdown selection in the app,  I have the pipe module declared in app module, and registered as a provider for the component I want to use it in but I get an error saying can't find pipe with name.  Below is the relevant code and how I'm trying to use it.  Am I declaring the pipe incorrectly or registering incorrectly?

**highlight-text.pipe.ts** taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44962110/11881461

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'highlightText'
})

export class HighlightTextPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any, args: any): any {
        if (!args) {return value;}
        var re = new RegExp(args, 'gi'); //'gi' for case insensitive and can use 'g' if you want the search to be case sensitive.
        return value.replace(re, "<mark>$&</mark>");
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    {other declarations},
    HighlightTextPipe
  ],
```

**page.component.ts**

```
import {HighlightTextPipe} from '../../pipes/highlight-text.pipe';

@Component({
  {other declarations}
  providers: [HighlightTextPipe]
})
```

How I'm trying to use it in **page.component.html**:

```
<span>{{ text | highlightText : 'Annex'}}</span>
```

The error I am getting:

```
Error: src/app/components/page.component.html:89:69 - error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'highlightText'.

89           <span>{{text | highlightText : 'Annex'}}</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Pipe actually isn't really a provider. If you define it on a module, you have to put it in the `declarations: [...]` section.

Having said that, a component doesn't have a `declaration` section.

So, that means, you cannot declare a pipe on a component. You can however declare it on a module, which will make it available to all components in that module. (See discussion: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29763 )

(However, if you do want to limit the scope to one component, then you could of course create a module for that specific component.)

Comment: This solved it for me thank you!  For anyone with a similar issue,  using a shared module for all components that should have the pipe works (for me the components that needed it weren't actually part of app module as I found out)